# how to remove hole in polygon from oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial, oracle-spatial

I have polygon [image: polygon]

it is a geometry!

`MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 2400000, null, 
MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), 
MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(
8432760.28444425, 4547222.21132491, 
8432767.40437640, 4547207.64930884, 
8432787.32577175, 4547207.51350532, 
8432781.00917312, 4547223.73964561, 
8432760.28444425, 4547222.21132491))`

and I draw it hole 
[image: polygon with hole]

it is a geometry!

`MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 2400000, null, 
MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1, 11, 2003, 1), 
MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(
8432760.2844442501664161682128906250, 4547222.211324909701943397521972656250, 
8432767.404376400634646415710449218750, 4547207.649308839812874794006347656250, 
8432787.325771750882267951965332031250, 4547207.513505320064723491668701171875, 
8432781.009173119440674781799316406250, 4547223.739645609632134437561035156250, 
8432760.2844442501664161682128906250, 4547222.211324909701943397521972656250, 
8432777.8091080002486705780029296875, 4547210.60657539963722229003906250, 
8432768.0091079995036125183105468750, 4547215.702575399540364742279052734375, 
8432777.9211079999804496765136718750, 4547219.79057539999485015869140625, 
8432777.8091080002486705780029296875, 4547210.60657539963722229003906250))`

How I can remove hole in polygon? that return me first geometry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sdo_util.extract to get the first ring of the first element.

```
select sdo_util.extract(mdsys.sdo_geometry(2003
                                          ,2400000
                                          ,null
                                          ,mdsys.sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1003, 1, 11, 2003, 1)
                                          ,mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array(8432760.2844442501664161682128906250
                                                                   ,4547222.211324909701943397521972656250
                                                                   ,8432767.404376400634646415710449218750
                                                                   ,4547207.649308839812874794006347656250
                                                                   ,8432787.325771750882267951965332031250
                                                                   ,4547207.513505320064723491668701171875
                                                                   ,8432781.009173119440674781799316406250
                                                                   ,4547223.739645609632134437561035156250
                                                                   ,8432760.2844442501664161682128906250
                                                                   ,4547222.211324909701943397521972656250
                                                                   ,8432777.8091080002486705780029296875
                                                                   ,4547210.60657539963722229003906250
                                                                   ,8432768.0091079995036125183105468750
                                                                   ,4547215.702575399540364742279052734375
                                                                   ,8432777.9211079999804496765136718750
                                                                   ,4547219.79057539999485015869140625
                                                                   ,8432777.8091080002486705780029296875
                                                                   ,4547210.60657539963722229003906250))
                       ,1
                       ,1) geometry
  from dual
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_util-extract.htm#SPATL1228